# Nginx redirect host to another application's subdirectory

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to redirect :

```
AAA.myhost.com --> http://127.0.0.1:888/AAA
BBB.myhost.com --> http://127.0.0.1:888/BBB
```

first : is it possible to do this ?
second : I know how to redirect to internal app ...
my nginx config :

```
worker_processes 1;

user root root;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;

events {
   worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
   accept_mutex off; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
}

http {
   include mime.types;

   upstream wordpress {
       server 127.0.0.1:888 fail_timeout=0;
   }

   default_type application/octet-stream;
   access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;
   sendfile on;

   server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     return 444;
   }

   server {
     listen 80 deferred;
     client_max_body_size 1M;

   server_name www.host.com;

   keepalive_timeout 5;

   location / {
       rewrite /wordpress redirect;
       try_files $uri @proxy_to_wordpress;
   }

   location @proxy_to_wordpress {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://wordpress;
   }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. Just add a `server` block for each subdomain, that includes the `proxy_pass` directive to your destination. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aaa.example.com;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:888;
}
```

You might want to look at different proxy configuration directives to modify its behavior.